# How do I vertically align varied sized figures within a bootstrap image carousel

Tags: html, css, image, carousel, figure

The issue I am having which is slowly starting to infuriate me is that I have an image carousel containing images of varying widths and heights. To explain things easier I have assigned inline styles with border colours. I have horizontally centered everything perfectly fine, however I am now trying to vertically center align the figure (image and caption) the green box to the carousel-inner which is the gold box. Currently all the figures are clipping to the top of the carousel-inner container.

The HTML for the carousel is shown below:

```
<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="10000">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
     <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
     <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
     <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
 </ol>
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid gold;">
 <div class="item active wraptocenter">
    <figure style="border:1px solid green;">
         <a href="images/gallery-misc/image1.png" target="_blank"><img src="images/gallery-misc/image1.png" style="border:1px solid red;"  alt="Image 1"></a>
    <figcaption style="border:1px solid black;">
        <h4>Figure Title</h4>
        <p>Figure Description (approx 3 Lines) Line 1<br>Line2<br>Line3.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
<div class="item wraptocenter">
    <figure style="border:1px solid green;">
         <a href="images/gallery-misc/image2.png" target="_blank"><img src="images/gallery-misc/image2.png" style="border:1px solid red;"  alt="Image 2"></a>
    <figcaption style="border:1px solid black;">
        <h4>Figure Title</h4>
        <p>Figure Description (approx 3 Lines) Line 1<br>Line2<br>Line3.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
<div class="item wraptocenter">
    <figure style="border:1px solid green;">
         <a href="images/gallery-misc/image3.png" target="_blank"><img src="images/gallery-misc/image3.png" style="border:1px solid red;"  alt="Image 3"></a>
    <figcaption style="border:1px solid black;">
        <h4>Figure Title</h4>
        <p>Figure Description (approx 3 Lines) Line 1<br>Line2<br>Line3.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</div>                 
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

The CSS I have used is shown here:

```
.wraptocenter { 
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;    
vertical-align: middle;   
}

figcaption h4, figcaption p {
text-align:center;
padding: 0px 60px 0px 60px; 
}

div.item figure {
vertical-align:middle;
}

#mycarousel {
width:1100px;
height:1100px;
}

#mycarousel img {
max-width:850px;
max-height:850px;
width:auto;
height:auto;
}
```

I tried using #mycarousel figure rather than image but it blew the image up to its original very large size. If anybody could give me some pointers that would be really appreciated. The rest of the carousel functionality works fine.

Thanks

Comment: what are the sizes of those img? same or different?

Answer (score 0):

Since bootstrap are setting `item` as `display: block`,
I would suggest updating your class like this:

```
.wraptocenter {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 30%;
}
```

Option 1:

```css
.wraptocenter {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

figcaption h4,
figcaption p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 60px 0px 60px;
}

div.item figure {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#mycarousel {
  width: 100%;
}

#mycarousel img {
  width: auto;
  height: 450px;
}

.outer__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 1100px;
  height: 1100px;
}

.carousel-indicators{
 top: 75%;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="outer__wrapper">

  <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="10000">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid gold;">
      <div class="item active wraptocenter">
        <figure style="border:1px solid green;">
          <a href="images/gallery-misc/image1.png" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x300" style="border:1px solid red;" alt="Image 1"></a>
          <figcaption style="border:1px solid black;">
            <h4>Figure Title</h4>
            <p>Figure Description (approx 3 Lines) Line 1
              <br>Line2
              <br>Line3.</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="item wraptocenter">
        <figure style="border:1px solid green;">
          <a href="images/gallery-misc/image2.png" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" style="border:1px solid red;" alt="Image 2"></a>
          <figcaption style="border:1px solid black;">
            <h4>Figure Title</h4>
            <p>Figure Description (approx 3 Lines) Line 1
              <br>Line2
              <br>Line3.</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="item wraptocenter">
        <figure style="border:1px solid green;">
          <a href="images/gallery-misc/image3.png" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x700" style="border:1px solid red;" alt="Image 3"></a>
          <figcaption style="border:1px solid black;">
            <h4>Figure Title</h4>
            <p>Figure Description (approx 3 Lines) Line 1
              <br>Line2
              <br>Line3.</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Option 2:

```css
.wraptocenter {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 30%;
}

figcaption h4,
figcaption p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 60px 0px 60px;
}

div.item figure {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#mycarousel {
  width: 1100px;
  height: 1100px;
}

#mycarousel img {
  max-width: 850px;
  max-height: 850px;
  height: 450px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="10000">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid gold;">
    <div class="item active wraptocenter">
      <figure style="border:1px solid green;">
        <a href="images/gallery-misc/image1.png" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1500" style="border:1px solid red;" alt="Image 1"></a>
        <figcaption style="border:1px solid black;">
          <h4>Figure Title</h4>
          <p>Figure Description (approx 3 Lines) Line 1<br>Line2<br>Line3.</p>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="item wraptocenter">
      <figure style="border:1px solid green;">
        <a href="images/gallery-misc/image2.png" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/900x400" style="border:1px solid red;" alt="Image 2"></a>
        <figcaption style="border:1px solid black;">
          <h4>Figure Title</h4>
          <p>Figure Description (approx 3 Lines) Line 1<br>Line2<br>Line3.</p>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="item wraptocenter">
      <figure style="border:1px solid green;">
        <a href="images/gallery-misc/image3.png" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/1500x500" style="border:1px solid red;" alt="Image 3"></a>
        <figcaption style="border:1px solid black;">
          <h4>Figure Title</h4>
          <p>Figure Description (approx 3 Lines) Line 1<br>Line2<br>Line3.</p>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks so much for that! The images are now centered vertically. One visual aesthetic is that they slide in positioned at the top and then drop to the center which looks a bit clunky. Do you know if there is a way they can slide in already centered?

Comment: @NerveWrack oh yes, `item` having a `display: block` which cause this problem, hmm let me try something..

Comment: @NerveWrack Not having a perfect solution right now, what is simple to achieve what you need is to add `margin-top: xx%;` to your `wraptocenter`, check my updated code.

Comment: @NerveWrack how about this? https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/7wu044fu/2/

Comment: @NerveWrack for img to fit the container, you can use fixed height but auto width   `width: auto; height: 450px;` for `img`

Comment: Thanks for letting me look at the fiddle. The images in the figures are all of different proportions, so when I made those amendments the same thing happens it arrives in at the top and then falls to the center. If you tried it with different placeholders say 600 by 400, 500 by 800 and say 250 by 700 for instance, it will probably still bug out.

Comment: you beat me to it, that's more like it. i'll give it a try and see how it comes out.

Comment: @NerveWrack have you tried my updated answer? that fixed the problem I think

Comment: do you reckon adding classes for square, portrait and landscape would help and assign each image which satisfies those criteria the relevant classes?

Comment: @NerveWrack if you are putting those img together, they should have similar ratio...... I have been work for many companies and worked with many designers you need to make those img same sizes for best visual. If not you might need to chop the img dynamically.

Comment: it kind of did. visually speaking the net result is good, however I then get a bouncing resizing carousel container and all of my indicators are then stuck on top of the description part of the figure. So now I need to work that out. Solve one problem, create two more. C'est la vie.

Comment: @NerveWrack maybe this one: https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/7wu044fu/4/?